# Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric when converting nvarchar to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in sql which is sometimes nvarchar and number in some cases. The column has a datatype nvarchar . I am just interested in the places where its numeric where none numeric i dont need it. I use case like below

```
(SELECT case when isnumeric(dia) =1   then dia else '' end as days from dbo.Debtor  )
```

the above query works fine and return the record where is numeric and empty where is null. However, i want to return my records as decimal or float. I because i want to be able to filter like

```
SELECT .....
   WHERE EXISTS(
                (SELECT case when isnumeric(dia) =1   
                 then dia else '' end as days from dbo.Debtor  ) > 0

               )
```

The above is just an example but didnt tested. Please my Problem now is when i cast my column dia to decimal i get the error  "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric".

Below is my query .

```
(SELECT case when isnumeric(dia) =1   then
           cast(dia as decimal(3,1))    else 0 end as de from dbo.Debtor  )
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: TRY_CONVERT function?

Comment: `Decimal(3,2)` means largest number you can use is 9.99. Are you sure that's right for you and you don't have larger values in `dia` column?

Comment: Sorry sir. its decimal(3,1). Thank you.

Comment: ISNUMERIC returns 1 for a lot of things that will not fit in a decimal(3,1). Try with `ISNUMERIC(dia + 'e0') = 1 AND LEN(dia) <= 5 AND ABS(CONVERT(decimal(6,1), dia))) < 100`

Comment: Please can you explain the logic behind your query ? why do i need the len() and the ABS(CONVERT(decimal(6,1), dia))) < 100 ? pls explain sir. Its of great help.

Comment: @adrianm is correct; in my case `ISNUMERIC(X)=1` returns `TRUE` when `X` is equal to `-`

Answer (score 3):

In order to evaluate only numeric values you need to have isnumeric in where part.
try something like

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT cast(dia as decimal(3,1)) from dbo.Debtor WHERE isnumeric(dia) =1 ),0)
```

Comment: it fails sir Thank you for the effort. It help though i am trying harder.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone of you who is encountering this error, the solution is simple. If you can see in his example, he uses this convertion

```
cast(dia as decimal(3,1))
```

for example, he has a data which is `100.0007` his implicit conversion will result in the said error because he want `three(3)` numbers with `one(1)` decimal point only `(3,1)`.

The solution to this is to actually checking the length of the data and determine, how many digits do you actually want.

In most cases this conversion is sufficient.

```
cast(dia as decimal(18,4))
```

But if your data has more numbers AFTER the decimal point, then change the conversion as needed.

```
cast(dia as decimal(18,5))
```

and so forth....

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dbms is evaluating `cast(dia as decimal(3,2))` in any case. To avoid that swap numeric check and cast:

```
SELECT cast(case when isnumeric(dia) = 1 then dia else null end as decimal(3,2)) from dbo.Debtor
```

Comment: Thank you . i tried but i get the Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Ah, maybe converting '' to decimal fails. I'll update my answer ans replace '' with NULL.

Comment: Arithmetic overflow. Still fails.

Comment: So one of the values is considered numeric, but doesn't fit in decimal(3,2). Try something like decimal(15,5) to check this.

Comment: Yah u re right . I tried 15,5 and 17,5 since but all fails. I just am confused.

Comment: Okay. So it looks like either there is a value even longer/bigger in your table (something like '5E100' or '12345678901234567890') or ISNUMERIC is lying or at least not compatible with CAST. Does ISNUMERIC work with thousand separators, trailing minus, etc., which maybe CAST is not capable of? Check your data and look out for suspicous values.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this error, we need examples such as inserting into a table

```
Declare @@test table(test numeric(8,2))
```

But when you insert data with more than 8 characters
Then the error message appears

```
insert into @@test
values ('11190000.1212')
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 3 Arithmetic overflow error
> converting varchar to data type numeric. The statement has been
> terminated.